# Get element id using the custom tag value jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get element id using the custom tag value jquery ?

```
<div id="1" tab_id="4" class="div_focus" tabindex="1">This is label A</div>
```

how can i get value of id where tab_id = 4 using jquery ?

Comment: Just FYI, creating your own attributes on elements will cause your code to become invalid and may cause rendering issues in some browsers. If you can, use HTML5 `data-*` attributes instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [**Demo On JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3BchV/3/)

try out this selector

```
$('div[tab_id = "4"]').attr("id")
```

check : [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: @NitinKabra - its working check the jsfiddle ...i just ran and its working fine....go to link and check what you missed...

Answer (score 5):

```
var id = $('[tab_id="4"]').attr('id');
```

And if there is multiple element with `tab_id="4"`, and you need to get all the ids, then use:

```
var ids = $('[tab_id="4"]').map(function() {
  return this.id;
});
```

Comment: @NitinKabra Then there is other problem of your code. Just check the work sample http://jsfiddle.net/hntmc/.

Answer (score 1):

```
 jQuery('[tab_id="4"]').attr('id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [attributes selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('div[tab_id="4"]').prop('id')
```

or

```
$('div[tab_id="4"]')[0].id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = $('div[tab_id="4"]').prop("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

use `attr()`

```
$('div[tab_id="4"]').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

For Wordpress users, It was tricky for me to figure out!! All I had to do is replace `$` with `jQuery`

**Working Example:**

```
var ytid = jQuery('div[class="vi-responsive yt-light"]').attr("data-mid");
```

**Wrong Example:**

```
var ytid = $('div[class="vi-responsive yt-light"]').attr("data-mid");
```